# Assign a value to the first row of a sub-dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gp_id': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

   gp_id  A
0      1  1
1      2  2
2      1  3
3      2  4
```

I want to assign the value `-1` to the first row of the group with the id 2 (gp_id = 2), to get the following output:

```
   gp_id  A
0      1  1
1      2 -1
2      1  3
3      2  4
```

To do this, I've tried the following code:

```
df[df.gp_id == 2].A.iloc[0] = -1
```

But this doesn't do anything as I'm assigning a value in the sub-dataframe `df[df.gp_id == 2]` and I'm not modifying the original dataframe `df`.

Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.loc[(df.gp_id == 2).argmax(), 'A'] = -1
```

as `pd.Series.argmax` returns the first max.

If you are not sure that the value is present in the dataframe, you could do:

```
cond = (df.gp_id == 2)
if cond.sum():
    df.loc[cond.argmax(), 'A'] = -1
```

Comment: thanks jazrael, this works if we are sure that the value is present in the dataframe

Comment: Thank you, the first solution works perfectly in my case as I'm sure the value is present !

Answer (score 1):

General solution if possible mask return no rows is chain another mask by cumulative sum of mask by `&` for bitwise `AND` and set values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df.gp_id == 2
df.loc[m & (m.cumsum() == 1), 'A'] = -1
```

Working well if no match - no assign, no error, no incorrect assignment:

```
m = df.gp_id == 7
df.loc[m & (m.cumsum() == 1), 'A'] = -1
```

---

Solution if always match mask at least one row is:

```
idx = df[df.gp_id == 2].index[0]

df.loc[idx, 'A'] = -1
print (df)
   gp_id  A
0      1  1
1      2 -1
2      1  3
3      2  4
```

If no match, solution raise error, no incorrect assignment.

Comment: Thank you, the 3 solutions are working in my case. If I'm not mistaking, for the third one it could be simplified like this : `idx = df[df.gp_id == 2].index[0]`

Comment: @LeoGlt - yop, agree.

Comment: The first sentence is incomprehensible. Can you fix it?